# WebSphere Liberty Java Batch Can we Pass Batchlet step Output to Chunk step as a Input Parameter runtime

Tags: websphere-liberty

In WebSphere Liberty Java Batch,
Is it possible to pass first Step Output to Next step as input parameter.
e.g. First step is Batchlet and second step is chunk. Once first step completes its execution output should be passed to second step runtime..

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you are thinking of this in z/OS JCL terms where a step would write output to a temporary dataset that gets passed to a subsequent step.  JSR-352 doesn't get into dataset (or file) allocation.  That's up to the application code.  So you could certainly have a step that wrote output into a file (or dataset) and a later step could certainly read from that same file (or dataset) if it knew the same.  You could make the name into a job property that was provided as a property to the batchlet and reader.  You could even externalize the value of the job property as a job parameter.
But nothing is going to delete the file for you at the end of the job (like a temporary dataset would get deleted).  You'll need to clean up the file yourself.
Is that what you were asking?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the JobContext user data: **JobContext.set/getTransientUserData()**.

This does not however allow you to populate a batch property (via **@Inject @BatchProperty**) in a parallel way to the manner in which you can supply values from XML via substitution with job parameters.

We have raised an [issue](https://java.net/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=7475) to consider an enhancement for the next revision of the Batch specification to allow a property value to be set dynamically from an earlier portion of the execution.

In the meantime there is also the possibility to use CDI bean scopes to share information across steps, but this also is not integrated with batch property injection.